# Obtener la media diagonal de una matriz

Tags: python

Tengo que sacar la media de la diagonal de una matriz

```
 a = int()
 promedio = int()
 i = int()
 j = int()
 a = [[int() for ind0 in range(3)] for ind1 in range(3)]
 promedio = 0
 for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,4):
        a[i-1][j-1] = int(input())
        if i==j:
            promedio = promedio+a[i-1][j-1]/a[i-1][j-1]
 print(" el promedio es ",promedio)
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada las primeras 4 lineas están de mas, en python, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, no es necesario declarar el tipo de dato antes de ser usado, por lo que poner `i = int()` es lo mismo que poner `i = 0`, que supongo tu quieres declararlo para el `for`, pero no es necesario, en python basta con poner `for i in range(3)`.

Los dos `for` que tienes están en un `range(1,4)` y tus indices asi `[i-1][j-1]` esto puedes modificarlo por `range(3)` como lo tienes en la declaración de tu matriz y asi acceder a tu matriz con `[i][j]`

ahora el porque no te da el promedio correcto es porque en la linea `promedio = promedio + a[i-1][j-1]/a[i-1][j-1]` estas dividiendo el numero ingresado por si mismo y eso siempre dará como resultado `1`, por lo cual solo le estas sumando a la variable promedio `1`, la división la tienes que hacer al final de leer datos. te anexo el código de como debería quedar.

```
a = [[int() for ind0 in range(3)] for ind1 in range(3)]
promedio = 0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i][j] = int(input())
        if i==j:
            promedio = promedio + a[i-1][j-1]
print(" el promedio es ",promedio/3)
```

El código puede optimizarse un poco, pero veo que aprendes y no quiero confundirte, espero sea lo que buscas

Comment: Disculpame Luis alejandro, es que el codigo no me deja ejecutarlo en la consola.Que le podria anexar para que funcione

Comment: como lo estas intentando ejecutar y que mensaje te manda?

Answer (score 0):

En python cuando hablas de matrices es sinónimo de usar Numpy, puedes obtener la media de la diagonal en solo 1 linea, no tienes que reinventar la rueda.

```
import numpy as np

# Toma todos los datos antes de hacer cualquier cálculo

# Conviertes la lista de listas en un array de numpy
a = np.array(a)
# Obtienes la diagonal, y a esto le sacas la media
np.mean(np.diag(a))
```